# On the definition of support of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I can't understand the definition of support of a scheme precisely (in Zariski site).  For example, let $X=Spec(k[x,y])$ and $x\in O_X$ be a global section. Then what is the support of $x$?

Comment: For a section $s$ of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules, the support is the locus of points $p\in X$ where the image of $s$ in the _stalk_ $\mathcal{F}_p$ is nonzero. You should arrive at your expected result with this definition.

Comment: @KReiser so the support in my case is the whole $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a ring and $M$ an $A$-module, then the support of $m\in M$ (thought of as a section of the associated sheaf on $Spec(A)$ consists of all prime ideals $p$ such that there is no $u\in A-p$ with $um=0$. So for example if $A$ is an integral domain and $M$ torsion-free, then any nonzero $m\in M$ has support the whole of $Spec(A)$. (Your case is $A=k[x,y]$.)